OSM Web Wizard creating additional files
I'm attempting to ensure the creation of XML files when launching the OSM web wizard. For example:
self.filename("config", ".sumocfg")
        opts = [sumo, "-n", self.files_relative["net"], "--gui-settings-file", self.files_relative["guisettings"],
                "--duration-log.statistics",
                "--device.rerouting.adaptation-interval", "10",
                "--emission-output","emissions.xml",
                "--fcd-output","fcd-output.xml",
                "--device.rerouting.adaptation-steps", "18",
                "-v", "--no-step-log", "--save-configuration", self.files_relative["config"], "--ignore-route-errors"]

Here, I've ensured the creation of FCD and emission output files. However, I'm encountering difficulties in creating an additional output file. How can I achieve this?"
I found that the line adding the additional files to the options is:
if len(self.additionalFiles) > 0:
            opts += ["-a", ",".join(self.getRelative(self.additionalFiles))]

However, this does not create the file.
I also attempted to force writing, but with no results:
with open("edge_emission_output.xml", "a") as f:
    f.write("""
    <additional> 
        <edgeData id="dump" type="emissions" file="emissions-dump.xml" excludeEmpty="true"/>
    </additional>
    """)


The osmWebWizard script has a mechanism of registering files first before writing to them.
So you need to do
self.filename("edge_emission_output", ".xml")
    with open(self.files["edge_emission_output"], 'w') as f:
        ...

and then
self.additionalFiles.append(self.files["edge_emission_output"])

